# How to get sudo to prompt you for a password each time

Tags: command-line, password, sudo, root, execute-command

I find that if I execute something using `sudo` that then if I execute something else soon after also using `sudo`, that it does not prompt me for my password, and although this can be inconvenient in some situations, it is a security risk in others, and a hassle to keep on coming back and executing the command to make it prompt your for the password on the next go. So I was wondering if and how I could get it to prompt me every time, or for it to at least only remember my password for a very short amount of time?

Comment: In the opposite situation, if you work in a low-risk environment, constant prompting is incredibly irritating. Thanks for your question because the solution is essentially the same: change the timeout.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open Terminal and type:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then scroll down to the line that reads:

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

And change it to:

```
Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=0
```

You can change `0` to any values (time in minutes). Setting it to `0` will ask for your password every time and `-1` will make it never ask. The default is `15` according to `man sudo 8`, but [some manuals](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) say the default is `5`. Have a look at the [RootSudoTimeout](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout) wiki for more information.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to finish editing, <kbd>Y</kbd> to save changes, and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to exit.

Comment: What's the default timeout period?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. 15 mins according to `man sudo 8`, but [some](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) manual says 5

Comment: Believe the manual you have on your system. Different distributions can chose their own defaults.

Comment: Believe the source, rather than the manual.

Answer (score 0):

From Terminal run:

```
echo "testuser1  ALL=(ALL)   PASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Or:

```
visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

Add the following line at the bottom of the file:

```
testuser1 ALL=(ALL)   PASSWD: ALL
```