# How to create a alias for running a server and its client simultaneously

Tags: command-line, server, alias, client, xterm

I'm trying to create an "alias" to run a server in a separate terminal, then after a few seconds open its client, this is the command I'm trying:

```
alias kingp='xterm -e sudo /opt/king-phisher/KingPhisherServer -L INFO -f /opt/king-$/king-phisher/server_config.yml; /opt/king-phisher/KingPhisher'
```

The problem with this is that it does not run the second command until I close the server (CTRL+C), and them it runs the client normally, I've tried with & and && at the end of the server command to no avail, it seems like the server, even being run with -e is still not liberating the terminal for the other command to run, I've been successful with -e before and have no idea why in a alias it does not work, anyone can help me? thank you very much guys.

Comment: IMHO aliasis are nice for simple commands, but as the commands get more complex, better to run a script. Is there some reason you need to run xterm here ? try alias kingp='sudo /opt/king-phisher/KingPhisherServer -L INFO -f /opt/king-$/king-phisher/server_config.yml; /opt/king-phisher/KingPhisher` I am not sure where you want an & but your problem is likely due to calling xterm. If you write a script, however, your alias is simply `alias kingp='sudo /path/to/script`

Comment: Thanks I'm trying with a script but the server keeps executing one after another, it enters a infinity loop and never jumps to the next command, I think it has something to do with the parammeters that are being passed to the server (the -L etc..), gonna keep digging, thank you fort your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the alias is first interpreted by Bash, and then by XTerm.

Bash interprets the whole alias as two separate commands: `xterm -e sudo /opt/king-phisher/KingPhisherServer -L INFO -f /opt/king-$/king-phisher/server_config.yml` and `/opt/king-phisher/KingPhisher`, and the commands are executed one after the other in the current shell.

Using `&` instead of `;` won't help, because Bash will still interpret `&`; escaping `;` or `&` won't help either, because XTerm has no notion of Bash syntax, and will pass either `;` or `&` as an argument to `/opt/king-phisher/KingPhisherServer` (along with the remainder of the command, `/opt/king-phisher/KingPhisher`).

The only solution is to tell XTerm to invoke Bash and let Bash do the parsing:

```bsh
alias kingp="xterm -e bash -c 'sudo /opt/king-phisher/KingPhisherServer -L INFO -f /opt/king-$/king-phisher/server_config.yml & /opt/king-phisher/KingPhisher'"
```

Unless you user doesn't need to provide a `sudo` password in order to run `/opt/king-phisher/KingPhisherServer`, this will lead to the server not starting because of the `sudo` command being backgrounded before being able to read the password; see here for possible solutions: [How do I run a sudo command needing password input in the background?](https://askubuntu.com/q/750419/380067).