# How to always enforce sudo password for specific command?

Tags: command-line, server, sudo

The other day I was doing some maintenance tasks on my web server. I was in hurry and sleepy, so I did everything using `sudo` command.

And then, I accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, sending this command to my web server:

```
sudo rm -rf /*
```

*For those wondering what above command does: This deleted my **whole** web server*

Luckily, I had backups and sadly, I had to spend two more hours being awake to fix this awesome error. But since then, I have been wondering:

**Is there a way to always enforce sudo password for specific command?**

If the server asked me for a password, I would save myself from lot of trouble. It did not, because I ran about 5 `sudo` commands before this majestic error.

So, is there a way to do it? I just need the password with the `rm` command to always be enforced. Other commands I am using are usually `nano` or `cp` which both are (to some extent) revertable.

Comment: Related: [How to get sudo to prompt you for a password each time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636092/how-to-get-sudo-to-prompt-you-for-a-password-each-time)

Comment: I thought `--preserve-root` would prevent that ? But it seems to work only for `rm -rf /` and `rm -rf /*` ??

Comment: @solsTiCe `/*` is expanded before it is passed to the rm command. So the command doesn't see a single argument, but a list of arguments (`/bin /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home` ...)

Comment: One important lesson to take away from this is that you shouldn't run things with sudo unless you really need to. I know that doesn't answer what you asked here, but the overarching question is how to (hopefully) prevent yourself from deleting your server again, and avoiding sudo should be your first line of defense against that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set up a password for the 'rm' command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865023/how-can-i-set-up-a-password-for-the-rm-command)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That is not a duplicate question at all, the op here doesn't want the `rm` command to have a password. They just want `sudo` to prompt for one every time the rm command is used. The solution to the question you linked would become slightly annoying when your first command is `sudo rm`. As it will ask you for two passwords, one for `sudo` one for `rm`.

Comment: I strongly second David Z: _never use sudo without need_. Even if you reckon a command might need sudo, better first run it without, and only if it doesn't work hit `↑` `HOME` and [add the `sudo`](https://www.xkcd.com/149/). Furthermore, also never use `rm -rf` unless you've determined for sure it is needed. Stuff that might need deletion should normally not be write-protected.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Even easier with history expansion: To run the previous command line with a prefixed `sudo`, just execute `sudo !!`.

Comment: `su -c` also always asks for a password.

Comment: @MrLister Yes, but the `root` account is usually disabled (has no password) in Ubuntu and you cannot `su` to that account.

Comment: Another thing is to question why you are using `-f` (`--force`)? On the very rare occasion when I feel that I need to use that option, I first run `rm` without `--force`, and only then, if needed, with it. Any prompts highlight unexpected problems. I also have the habit of using the long options particularly on potentially destructive commands, which forces me to think twice about what I'm doing.

Answer (score 19):

You can set the `timestamp_timeout` to `0` for particular commands in `/etc/sudoers`.
Create a file `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/pduck` with the following content:

```
Cmnd_Alias DANGEROUS = /bin/rm

Defaults!DANGEROUS timestamp_timeout=0

pduck ALL = (ALL:ALL) DANGEROUS
```

Now the user `pduck` is always asked for a password when running `sudo rm` (no matter what additional parameters are given) even though the user is member of the `sudo` group and `sudo` remembers his password for other commands.

The downside is that you cannot easily add parameters to the `/bin/rm` line in the file to further restrict this. Well… you can, like:

```
Cmnd_Alias DANGEROUS = /bin/rm -f
```

but then you just get prompted for exactly `sudo rm -f` and not (again) for `sudo rm -rf`, for example.

Answer (score 9):

One method would be to use [safe-rm](https://launchpad.net/safe-rm). This will ONLY adress the usage of "rm" and preventing specific versions of "rm" to be run. That includes removing your root system but can also be used to prevent removing of system related directories like "/usr/" or "/var/". From the link:

> Reventing the accidental deletion of important files
>
> Safe-rm is a safety tool intended to prevent the accidental deletion
>   of important files by replacing `/bin/rm` with a wrapper, which checks
>   the given arguments against a configurable blacklist of files and
>   directories that should never be removed.
>
> Users who attempt to delete one of these protected files or
>   directories will not be able to do so and will be shown a warning
>   message instead:
>
> ```
> $ rm -rf /usr   
> Skipping /usr
> ```
>
> (Protected paths can be set both at the site and user levels.)
>
> Recovering important files you deleted by mistake can be quite hard.
>   Protect yourself today by installing safe-rm and reduce the likelihood
>   that you will need to contact a data recovery service!

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for the safecow

Answer (score 4):

`sudo` provides an option `-k, --reset-timestamp`, see [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sudo.8.html):

> When used in conjunction with a command or an option that may require a password, this option will cause sudo to ignore the user's
>                    cached credentials.  As a result, sudo will prompt for a password (if one is required by the security policy) and will not update
>                    the user's cached credentials.

You could write a simple wrapper for `sudo` testing for `rm -rf /*` and running

```bsh
sudo -k rm -rf /*
```

instead, e.g. like this:

```bsh
sudo ()                                                                                                                                                 
{ 
    [[ "$*" == "rm -rf /*" ]] && opt="-k";
    /usr/bin/sudo $opt "$@"
}
```

#### Example usage

Testing with `echo a` here.

```
$ sudo echo
[sudo] password for dessert: 

$ sudo echo

$ sudo echo a
[sudo] password for dessert: 
a
$ sudo echo a
[sudo] password for dessert: 
a
```

---

If you want to be asked *every* time you run `rm` in general, you can adapt the above function as follows:

```bsh
sudo () 
{ 
    [[ "$1" == "rm" ]] && opt="-k";
    /usr/bin/sudo $opt "$@"
}
```

---

If you want to *combine* both general command calls and specific command lines I recommend using `case`, e.g.:

```bsh
sudo () 
{ 
    case "$*" in 
        rm*)            opt="-k" ;;
        "mv /home"*)    opt="-k" ;;
        "ln -s /usr/bin/fish /bin/sh") opt="-k" && echo "Don't you dare!" ;;
        *)              opt="" ;;
    esac;
    /usr/bin/sudo $opt "$@"
}
```

Note that these approaches won't work if you run `sudo` with options – possible solutions are `[[ "$*" =~ " rm " ]]` to check for the string “rm” surrounded by spaces or `*" rm "*)` with `case` to catch any command line containing “ rm ”.

Comment: `[[ "$1" == "rm" ]] && opt="-k";` and how about `/bin/rm`?

Comment: @Rinzwind I think the function is easily adaptable to specific needs, especially the `case` approach.

Answer (score 3):

This answer doesn't address the `sudo` part of your question but on the other hand it addresses a way to mitigate the danger of accidental `rm` invocations for *any* user.

You can alias `rm` to `rm -I` which

- asks for confirmation as soon as it would delete a directory or more than 3 files
- *as long as you leave out `-f`* which overrides previous `-I` options.

`--one-file-system` is another possible safeguard against unintended deletion that I use in my `rm` alias.

Additionally, you need to ask Bash to expand aliases after `sudo` with a trailing space in the alias definition (see below).

### Set-up

To create such an alias use the command:

```sh
alias rm='rm -I --one-file-system'
alias sudo='sudo '
```

You can put it into your `~/.bashrc` or even `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

### Usage

```
$ sudo rm -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d /*
rm: remove all arguments?
```

To confirm type `yes` or its translation into your locale or the first letter of either word and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Any other input including none aborts the operation.