# How do I force `sudo` to ask for a password each time when a specific command is used?

Tags: command-line, sudo, password

Is there a way to force the `sudo` command to ask for a password each time when I'm using `sudo rm /path/file`?

I want to protect my self from stupid mistakes, committed due to low attention when I'm running some commands from the history.

Comment: In a normally setup system `sudo` asks for a password no matter what command you run.

Comment: @Pilot6, yes, but as you know, by default, within the next 15 minutes it doesn't ask. So I would want to force `sudo` to ask for a password each time when `rm` is engaged.

Comment: something like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/636092/how-to-get-sudo-to-prompt-you-for-a-password-each-time

Comment: Hello, @Kulfy, what you mean by `k` option?

Comment: @Kulfy, I've corrected the question. It is a (random) regular file.

Comment: @Kulfy, thanks, I've got it. I've added the following function in my `.bashrc`: `function sudo() { if [[ $@ =~ ^rm ]]; then /usr/bin/sudo -k $@; else /usr/bin/sudo $@; fi; }`. It works like a charm. I would ask you to write an answer once the question is reopen :)

Comment: Although it is related and of interest, I don't think this question is a duplicate of [How to get sudo to prompt you for a password each time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636092/how-to-get-sudo-to-prompt-you-for-a-password-each-time), because that question is about how to do it for all commands, and this question is about how to do it for a specific command. At least as written, the answers there don't explain how they would be adapted to apply to the single-command case asked about here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As noted in other answers, `sudo` can set a timeout on the cached credential timestamp. This can be done specifically for a given command using `Defaults` in `sudoers`:

```
Defaults!/bin/rm timestamp_timeout=0
```

Always remember to edit `sudoers` with `visudo`. I recommend a drop-in file in `/etc/sudoers.d` instead of editing `/etc/sudoers` directly. For example:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/always-ask-pass-for-rm
```

From [the manpage for `sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html):

> ### [Defaults](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Defaults)
>
> Certain configuration options may be changed from their default values
>   at run-time via one or more `Default_Entry` lines. These may affect
>   all users on any host, all users on a specific host, a specific user,
>   a specific command, or commands being run as a specific user. Note
>   that per-command entries may not include command line arguments. If
>   you need to specify arguments, define a `Cmnd_Alias` and reference
>   that instead.
>
> ```
> Default_Type ::= 'Defaults' |
>                  'Defaults' '@' Host_List |
>                  'Defaults' ':' User_List |
>                  'Defaults' '!' Cmnd_List |
>                  'Defaults' '>' Runas_List
>
> Default_Entry ::= Default_Type Parameter_List
>
> Parameter_List ::= Parameter |
>                    Parameter ',' Parameter_List
>
> Parameter ::= Parameter '=' Value |
>               Parameter '+=' Value |
>               Parameter '-=' Value |
>               '!'* Parameter
> ```

Note that it does say you can affect "commands being run as a specific user", but doesn't mention commands being run *by a specific user*, so it might not be possible to constrain it only for your user. The [examples in the manpage](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#EXAMPLES) don't include anything for that.

Comment: `ln -s /bin/rm rmdo; sudo ./rmdo <file>`

Comment: @bac0n I'm operating under the assumption that this is more to deter accidental gun-to-foot scenarios rather than to prevent deliberate attack. Otherwise one would be pretty dumb to allow arbitrary `sudo` commands for any account with shell access.

Comment: Great first time answer from a user account created just today! It's like my own answer below on steroids. Well done.

Comment: How do I adopt this method when there isn't any specific executable binary, for eg. Shell in-built commands?

Comment: @Kulfy How would you run a shell builtin with `sudo`?

Comment: @EliahKagan For example `sudo alias`? This might sound odd but I'm just curious.

Comment: @Kulfy `sudo` only runs external commands. `sudo alias` gives the error "sudo: alias: command not found" outside the unusual case that you *also* have an external command called `alias`. Some shells, like Bash, have some builtins that shadow external commands. If one tries to run them with `sudo`, one really runs the same-named external commands. For example, `sudo kill`, `sudo printf`, and `sudo echo` run external commands. See [Why doesn't \`sudo cd /var/named\` work?](https://askubuntu.com/q/291666), [Why is there a /bin/echo and why would I want to use it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/960822).

Comment: @EliahKagan I see. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `k` option with `sudo` to reset the timestamp.

If `sudo -k` is used as a command, it would expire/invalidate the cached credentials immediately.

But if `sudo -k` is used with some command, for example, `sudo -k rm /some/file`, the shell would ask for password even if some credentials are already cached. In this case, the new credentials won't be cached. That means if another command with `sudo` is executed after that, it won't ask for password (if credentials were cached previously).

From [sudo's manpage](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html):

> **-k [command]**
>
> When used alone, the
>   -k (kill) option to sudo invalidates the user's cached credentials. The next time sudo is run a password will be required. This option
>   does not require a password and was added to allow a user to revoke
>   sudo permissions from a .logout file. Not all security policies
>   support credential caching.
>
> When used in
>   conjunction with a command or an option that may require a password,
>   the -k option will cause sudo to ignore the user's cached credentials.
>   As a result, sudo will prompt for a password (if one is required by
>   the security policy) and will not update the user's cached
>   credentials.

If you want to make `sudo` to ask for password for specific commands without using `k` every time, you can define custom functions in `.bashrc`. For example, from [pa4080's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195719/how-do-i-force-sudo-to-ask-for-a-password-each-time-when-a-specific-command-is#comment2002944_1195719):

```
sudo() { if [[ $@ =~ ^rm ]]; then /usr/bin/sudo -k "$@"; else /usr/bin/sudo "$@"; fi; }
```

Comment: it is easy to circumvent by using full path to sudo so i think it gives a false sense of security.

Comment: @bac0n, I agree that this is easy to circumvent, but I don't think this means that it gives a false sense of security. The use-case here is like a fire alarm with a cover over it; the cover isn't to stop malicious users from triggering the alarm, it's to stop an inattentive user from accidentally leaning against the button. The fact that it's easy to deliberately bypass is kind of the intention, not an exploit.

Answer (score 3):

You can set sudo to always ask for a password:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset, timestamp_timeout=120, pwfeedback
#Defaults   mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

In my configuration I have sudo timeout set at 2 hours (120 minutes) before it asks for a password again. Setting it to `0` will require password every time you use `sudo`

Comment: Why set it to 1 minute? The OP asks for *no* caching of credentials; set it to 0.

Comment: But why so much emphasis on the values the user isn't asking about? Setting it to 0 seems like an afterthought, when it should be the entire answer.

Comment: @chepner I've revised answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## `rm` wrapper script

Sometime ago I wrote a wrapper script for the `rm` command:

- [How can I set up a password for the 'rm' command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865023/how-can-i-set-up-a-password-for-the-rm-command/866003#866003)

Some of the notable features:

- An encrypted password must be used each time `rm` is called unless it is being used within a batch job like `sudo apt-get` or `sudo update-grub`.
- Ensure top level directories are never removed even if a relative path was passed.
- Every time `rm` is used it is logged to `journalctl` and `/var/log/syslog`.